# Import contact group from outlook - excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code to import all contacts from Outlook.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olConItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olItem As Object
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set olConItems = olFolder.Items


 'HERE IS THE PROBLEM I do not know how to do so that there are only contacts from my desired group in the olConItems collection
For Each olItem In olConItems
    If TypeName(olItem) = "ContactItem" Then
    'Do something - no problem I just do not want to post unnecessary code
    End If
Next olItem
```

I need to import only those which belong to a certain contact group. How can I get the contacts group property? Is it somehow exposed?

Comment: Actually it is not. They want to send email via outlook inside outlook. I want to export the particular groups. They suggest to simply use the name of the group as the recipient. But it won't work in my case.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Finding the DL or exporting its members? What exactly do you mean by "export"? Saving as a file in a particular format? Or simply reading the properties?

Comment: Well by export I mean for example to copy them into my sheet by adding code to the `/*Do something*/` section. But that is not problem. My problem is that I donk know how to get the collection of contacts in some group in outlook. Lets say I have group called "Customers" and I want to use it as a source for the `for each` loop. But I dont know ho to acces this specific collection

Answer (score 0):

Loop from 1 to DistListItem.MemberCount and call DistListItem.GetMember - it will return Recipient object. If Recipient object properties are not enough, read Recipient.AddressEntry to get AddressEntry object.

Answer (score 0):

The subroutine retrieves names from the "MyGroupName" contact group
in Outlook and lists them in the active worksheet.

```
Sub Get_Email_List()

    Dim I As Integer    
    Dim A1 As String
    Dim B() As String
    Dim WSN as String
    Dim Group as String

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Object
    Dim myFolder As Object
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim WordApp As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    WSN = ActiveSheet.Name
    Group = "MyGroupName"

    Sheets(WSN).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    With olApp
        Set myNamespace = .GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
        Set myItem = myFolder.Items(Group)
        For I = 1 To myItem.MemberCount
            Cells(I + 1, 1) = myItem.GetMember(I).Name
            Cells(I + 1, 3) = myItem.GetMember(I).Address
        Next I
    End With
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set myNamespace = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set myItem = Nothing

    Range("A1") = "Display Name"
    Range("B1") = "Last Name"
    Range("C1") = "Email Address"
    Range("D1") = "Composite Email Address"
    Range("A2:B" & I + 1).Select
    Selection.Cells.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    A1 = ""
    I = 2
    While Cells(I, 1) > ""
        If InStr(1, Cells(I, 1), ")") > 0 Then _
            Cells(I, 1) = Left(Cells(I, 1), InStr(1, Cells(I, 1), "(") - 2)

        B = Split(Cells(I, 1), " ")
        Cells(I, 2) = Trim(B(UBound(B, 1)))
        If I > 1 Then A1 = A1 & "; "
        A1 = A1 & Trim(Cells(I, 1))
        Cells(I, 4) = Cells(I, 1) & " <" & Cells(I, 3) & ">"
        I = I + 1
    Wend

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSN).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSN).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & I), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSN).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:D" & I)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 28
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 48

    Range("A1:D1").Select
    Selection.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```